# Algorithm to calculate parents and children with values and distances

Tags: algorithm, graph

I know algorithms like dijkstra, prim, kruskal but I don't know how to do the following problem.

I've a list of cities with integer values. 
I've a function which calculates the distance of a given city depending on the distance range passed. If you pass to the function a city and a distance of 20km will return all cities that are at that distance from city given.

Conditions:

- I want to set up as parent all cities greater than a limit given value.
- If a parent city have other city parent within given distance with more value, set up as city parent city with more value and as child city with less value.
- For all children cities, set up as parent the city parent with more value within given distance and if there aren't parent city the child city won't have parent.

Sorry if I don't explain me very well.

**Edit:**

I added some pseudocode to try to help you with the answer:

```
//Get array of cities ordered ASC by value and each city is marked as parent or not.
$cities = getCitiesByValue(); 

foreach($cities as $city) {

  if($city->isParent) {
    //Get near(20km) PARENT cities ordered  ASC
    $nearCities = findNearBy($city, $distance = 20); 

    foreach($nearCities as $nearCity) {

      if($nearCity->value > $city->value) {
        $city->setParent($nCity);
        $city->setAsChild;
      }
    }
  }

  elseif($city->isChild) {
    //Get near(50km) PARENT cities ordered  ASC
    $nearCities = findNearBy($city, $distance = 50);

    foreach($nearCities as $nearCity) {

      if($nearCity->value > $city->value) {
        $city->setParent($nCity);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your explanation, but you should get started on a solution before posting here.

Comment: the explanation is a little bit confusing imho... :/

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is *excactly* a problem solveable by Dijkstra's algorithm (assuming of course no negative weights), with maintaining a `map:Verterx->Vertex` that will map from each vertex, to the vertex you used to "discover" it.

Comment: @Keyser I've all the functions to calculate city distances and near cities. If I set up cities ordered by values as parent recursively the result is wrong.@ amit Dijkstra calculates the minimum distance of the city given to all cities and I already have the distance to each city.

Comment: @Biruwon: You already have the distance to all cities and you just want to chose those shorter then 20KM? How is the data of distances orginized? is it an array? sorted array? Also, define in this casw what a "parent" and "children" cities are.

Comment: I suggest you rephrase the problem in more clear terms. What exactly is a city's "value"? What is the "weight"? What are "parents" and "children"? It would also help if you described the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than the data structure you are building to solve it.

Comment: @amit I already have the distance to all cities. Is it an array of cities ordered by distances. A "parent" city is one that his value is greater than a given limit value. A "child" city is the opposite. I've changed "weight" word by "value", sorry for this and for my english.

Comment: From your explanation the problem appars to be rather trivial -- assigning a certain attribute for each node based on the value of another attribute. What's the problem? Why do you think this requires some non-trivial algorithm?